# How can I collaborate on a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a YouTube playlist of various songs. I want to share the playlist with my friends so each of them can add or remove their own songs.

**Can I allow other users to add videos to my YouTube playlist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invite people to collaborate via the playlist settings.

[image]

HC article: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6109639?hl=en